# Click reinserts looped elements twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, concatenation

My code, upon click on "produce", takes words from a text area, loops, and concatenates the way I need it. 
All's good, all is working.

BUT

if I press "Clear" and click "produce" again, my code inserts the looped words twice.

Question: How can I always get the same result everytime I click "produce"?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/ugpuLq6w/10/)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="KWarea" rows="4" cols="50">*casio*
    *citizen*
    *clarks*
    </textarea>
<br>
<button id="produce">produce</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="result"></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="result">
    Expected result example:
        <br />
    ("*casio*","* casio *", "*citizen*", "* citizen *", "*clarks*", "* clarks *")
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var endString = "";
    $('#produce').click(function () {
        var myTxtArea = document.getElementById('KWarea');
        myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');

        var lines = $('#KWarea').val().replace(/\*/g, '').split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
            endString += '"*' + lines[i] + '*"' + ',' + '"* ' + lines[i] + ' *"' + ',';
          //   console.log(lines[i]);
        }
        var trimmedStr = endString.slice(0, -1);
        $('#result').html("Here is the final string:( " + trimmedStr + ")");

    });

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#result').empty();
    });

});
```

Comment: try to set `endString = "";` at the beginning of the produce function

Comment: 3 people answering same thing within 10 seconds lol

Comment: That's why stackoverflow does not cease to amaze me :). Jeremy got in first, will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: So do I understand correctly that my string, as a global variable, gets "filled up" with every event fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending string without emptying it first, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var endString = "";
    $('#produce').click(function () {
        var myTxtArea = document.getElementById('KWarea');
        myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');

        var lines = $('#KWarea').val().replace(/\*/g, '').split('\n');
        endString ='';
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
            endString += '"*' + lines[i] + '*"' + ',' + '"* ' + lines[i] + ' *"' + ',';
          //   console.log(lines[i]);
        }
        var trimmedStr = endString.slice(0, -1);
        $('#result').html("Here is the final string:( " + trimmedStr + ")");

    });

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#result').empty();
    });

});
```

Comment: or declare var endstring in $('#produce').click rather than your document.ready

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you have endString as a global variable. To fix this put 
`var endString = "";`
Inside of `$('#produce').click(function () {`

like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#produce').click(function () {
            var endString = "";
        var myTxtArea = document.getElementById('KWarea');
        myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');

        var lines = $('#KWarea').val().replace(/\*/g, '').split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
            endString += '"*' + lines[i] + '*"' + ',' + '"* ' + lines[i] + ' *"' + ',';
          //   console.log(lines[i]);
        }
        var trimmedStr = endString.slice(0, -1);
        $('#result').html("Here is the final string:( " + trimmedStr + ")");

    });

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#result').empty();
    });

});
```